# asp.net page error

Tags: asp.net

I have a Page in my asp.net website which I called FAQUSER.aspx this page works fine on my local server,but after I publish that project and upload it on the production server it gives me the following error,
The File 'FAQUSER.aspx.cs' doesnot exist

That's the only page of all the pages in my website that is giving this error,

So does anyone have any idea what could be the solution to that problem ??

Best Regards.

Comment: Can you post the `@ Page` directive from your `FAQUSER.aspx` file?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you upload the compiled binary/binaries for the project as well as the aspx files.

Comment: I already did that and as i said it's the only page that gives this error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XCopy publishing you should upload .cs files to the production server with .aspx files.